# using multiple BitBucket workspaces

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am new to BitBucket. I have created multiple workspaces within my account, one for each customers code base. I can use sourcetree to access the repos (succesfully push/pull/commit) but I can only clone from one of the workspaces. When I go to "Remote Repositories" only repo's from my main workspace are seen. I can still clone from the other workspaces using CLI, just not from sourcetree.

Am I incorrect in my usage of workspaces? I am essentially using them to separate my repos based on customers. This seems logical and neat to me rather than using projects. I use projects within the workspaces to group products etc....

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have the same/similar problem. It is not coding problem but how to select which workspace will be used when adding oAuth account into SourceTree from user interface? Looks like at the moment, the SourceTree will only use default (user's) workspace, but no way to see other workspaces and their repositories.
https://confluence.atlassian.com/get-started-with-sourcetree/connect-your-bitbucket-or-github-account-847359096.html

Comment: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Workspaces-and-repositories-not-showing-in-https-api-bitbucket/qaq-p/1967307